# Check if current DateTime is between certain percentage days - datetime ranges

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a start date: 01.01.2018 and 01.04.2018

How can I check if current date let's say 20.02.2018 is between 40%-60% between the start and end dates?

I think I have to convert everything to days and be something like:

EndDate - StartDate = 90 days

40% of 90 days is 36 days

60% of 90 days is 54 days

Today date is: 20.02.2018 => Today - StartDate = 50 days

50 days is between 36 and 54 so yes my date 20.02.2018 is between 40% and 60% of days passed in my range.

Is my approach correct ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve"

Comment: This is more of a mathematical question. It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Approach is dependent on your requirement. If you want to calculate the percentage based on start date then whatever you have done is right. If you want to calculate based on the end date then your approach is wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is nothing to do with actual programming problem, it is primarily focused on mathematical problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

```
DateTime today = Convert.ToDateTime("20.02.2018");
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.2018");
        DateTime End = Convert.ToDateTime("01.04.2018");
        TimeSpan diff = (End - start);
        double nrofdays = diff.TotalDays;
        double percentage = (((today) - (start)).TotalDays) / nrofdays * 100;
        if (percentage>=40 && percentage <= 60)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("yes my date 20.02.2018 is between 40% and 60%");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
private double CalculatePercentageInRange(DateTime start, DateTime end, DateTime d)
{
    TimeSpan periodTimeSpan = end - start; // Get length between start & end
    TimeSpan timespanFromStart = d - start; // Get length between datetime to check and start
    return timespanFromStart.TotalMilliseconds / periodTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds * 100;
}
```